# I am creating one object of class and making object null and then printing object ,it should not given exception or display nothing.why?

Tags: c#

I am creating one object of class and making object null and then printing object ,it should not given exception or display nothing.why?

```
class A
{

}
Main()
{
  A obj=new A();
  obj=null;
  Console.Write(obj);


}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking here.

Comment: You're sending `null` to the Console - what did you expect to see?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares i am asking for after i creating the object of class ,if i assign null value to that object and print it what should happen,what output i will get?

Comment: You could have just tried and asked for `Console.Write(null);`. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write` is [implemented like](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,aedbc5e502007cf7):

```
// Writes the text representation of an object to the text stream. If the
// given object is null, nothing is written to the text stream.
// Otherwise, the object's ToString method is called to produce the
// string representation, and the resulting string is then written to the
// output stream.
//
public virtual void Write(Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
        if (f != null)
            Write(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
        else
            Write(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

So when you pass the `null` value, nothing gets written, and no `ToString` method is called for the object. Hence no exception.

`ToString` implementation for an object is called in `Console.Write/WriteLine`, and if the object passed is `null` then it could raise the Null Reference Exception. That is *why* the passed value is checked at the entry of the method `if (value != null)`.

Comment: Now I understand Clearly,Thank you..!